# Increase jvm heap/stack size on activator

Tags: java, windows, playframework, typesafe-activator

Is there any ways to increase heap/stack size to compile my play application with activator on windows? Because activator command ignores -J parameters...

Comment: Use environment variable `JAVA_OPTS`.

Answer (score 0):

Try SBT_OPTS or ACTIVATOR_OPTS or activator -mem XY instead